# how to get the size and last modified date of file with fid

Tags: 8, files

Hi I have the filename and fid of the uploaded file in a media entity, how can I programatically get the size and last uploaded date in my module?  This is with D8
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to get the size:

```
 $tid=$fileupload[0]['target_id'];
 $file = File::load($tid);
 $size = $file->getSize();
```

Comment: Use like `\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($tid)` or add `use Drupal\file\Entity\File` at top of the file